# Discord.js sending a message in 1 minute intervals. TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: json, discord, discord.js

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    testchannel = client.channels.cache.get(channel => channel.id === '788449056682147870');


    setInterval(() => {
        testchannel.send("Hello");
    },1000);

    console.log ("ON");
});
```

There is a strange problem, please help

Comment: Two glaring problems: `testchannel` appears to be a global variable (prefix it with `let` to avoid this) and `client.channels.cache.get` may be returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, rate limits will prevent most of the messages in your interval from sending, and they will only be sent in small batches. Both Discord's API and discord.js do not allow bots to spam messages every second, for obvious reasons.

Second, the error implies that the channel (`testchannel`) is undefined. And that is for two reasons. First, the `Collection.get()` method uses an ID as its parameter, not a function. Second, the channel cache may not contain the specified channel, and you'll need to fetch it by making discord.js request the channel's info directly from the API instead of using the cache (if it isn't already in the cache).

Here's how you would do so:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    client.channels.fetch('788449056682147870').then(testchannel => {

        setInterval(() => {
            testchannel.send("Hello");
        }, 1000);

    });

    console.log ("ON");
});
```

Relevant resources:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get

Comment: Third, setInterval(fn, 1000) will repeat the action every second instead of every minute.